# How Can I Output a Remark Column with rowspan Without Duplicates for same group in Coldfusion (Re formated)

Tags: coldfusion

I am writing a Software for a company. Please friends, I want you to help me. This company is a paint company that has different Product Type and Paint Type and colors. A way bill will be generated showing the item no, the description, the quantity, and the remark. I am sorting by the Product Type and the Paint Type. I am also grouping the output.

Here, I want the remark to rowspan all the paint with the same Product Type and Paint Type. For instance, if the Product Type is Honey, and the Paint Type is Texture. If there are 5 Honey Texture with a quantity of 20, The remark should rowspan all the 5 honey texture and write "Total of 20 quantity for Honey Texture".  I tried looping but the values for quantity, description and item are repeated.

I don't want ITEM, QUANTITY, DESCRIPTION to be repeated. Only the Remark Column should rowspan the rows with the same product type and paint type. The Values in the ITEM, DESCRIPTION and QUANTITY should not be looped. See Picture for more explanation. I will be very grateful with any help.
Please, don't mind my html

```
<cfquery datasource="ysr" name="getlistofbuyings">
        SELECT p.*, pt.paintcode, pt.*, pp.producttypename, pts.paintype, l.*
        FROM purchase p, paint pt, producttype pp, painttype pts, litre l
        WHERE p.transactionid = #transactionid#
        AND p.paintid = pt.paintid
        AND pt.producttypeid = pp.producttypeid
        AND pt.painttypeid = pts.painttypeid
        AND pt.litreid = l.litreid
        ORDER BY pp.producttypename, pts.paintype ASC       
    </cfquery>


            <table id="items" bgcolor="">

             <a name="afteradding"> 
              <tr bgcolor="#ccccee">
                  <th>ITEM</th>
                  <th>QUANTITY</th>
                  <th  class="blank" colspan="3">DESCRIPTION</th>
                  <th>REMARKS</th>
              </tr>
              </a>    



              <cfoutput group="producttypename" query="getlistofbuyings">              
               <cfoutput group="paintype">             
               <cfoutput group="litrename">

<cfquery datasource="ysr" name="numvb">
                    SELECT p.*, COUNT(purchaseid) as pan, SUM(quantity) as quani, pa.*, py.*, pp.producttypename, l.litrename
                    FROM purchase p, paint pa, painttype py, producttype pp, litre l
                    WHERE p.transactionid = #transactionid#
                    AND p.paintid = pa.paintid
                    AND pa.painttypeid = py.painttypeid
                    AND pa.litreid = l.litreid
                    AND pa.producttypeid = #producttypeid#
                    AND py.painttypeid = #painttypeid#
                    AND pa.producttypeid = pp.producttypeid
                    AND l.litreid = #litreid#

                </cfquery>

                <cfquery datasource="ysr" name="kilop">
                    SELECT COUNT(purchaseid) as newpur
                    FROM purchase
                    WHERE transactionid = #transactionid#
                </cfquery>

                <cfset rowss = #numvb.pan#>
                <cfset tot = #numvb.quani#>

                <cfset arrOfUsers = ArrayNew(1)>
                <cfoutput>
                    <cfset ArrayAppend(arrOfUsers,'<td>'&getlistofbuyings.quantity&getlistofbuyings.producttypeid&getlistofbuyings.painttypeid&'</td>')>
                </cfoutput>

                <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(arrOfUsers)#" index="i">

                <tr class="item-row">

                <cfset curm = #getlistofbuyings.currentrow#>




                <th><cfoutput>#curm#</cfoutput></th>


                <th>#getlistofbuyings.quantity#</th>

                 <th colspan="3" class="description"><span> #producttypename# #paintype# #paintcolor# #paintcode#</span></th>
                <cfif i EQ 1>
                <th nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="#ArrayLen(arrOfUsers)#" >#tot# bags of #producttypename# #paintype# with #litrename#</th>
                </cfif>

              </tr>
            </cfloop>
                </cfoutput>
                </cfoutput>
                </cfoutput>][1]
```

Comment: Couple of observations: 1) `<cfapplication>` oriented stuff needs to be in `application.cfc` 2) You are opening yourself to all kinds of SQL injection attacks. See `<cfqueryparam>` 3) The 4 levels of `<cfoutput>` and one cfloop is just too must loop nesting. This code needs to be refactored. 4) The `<cfquery>` that is 3 levels into `<cfoutput>` is really hard to untangle. 5) The HTML table is not even going to be valid HTML

Comment: Please.. Since you got what i want, can i get a refactored code from you.. Please. Just help me. I am in urgent need of it

Comment: Do us a favour and format your code so it's readable, and only post the code that's relevant to your actual question. And as I recommended on Slack, read this http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html and this  http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
<!--- pseudo query --->
<cfscript>
  report = queryNew("productTypeName,paintType,paintColor,paintCode,quantity,litreName");
  queryAddRow(report, [["Honey","Texture","Brilliant White",1700,3,"20 litres"]]);
  queryAddRow(report, [["Honey","Texture","Off White",1701,8,"20 litres"]]);
  queryAddRow(report, [["Magic","Texture","Off White",1701,21,"20 litres"]]);
  queryAddRow(report, [["Magic","Texture","Brilliant White",1700,8,"20 litres"]]);
  queryAddRow(report, [["Princess","Gloss","Brilliant White",9102,9,"4 litres"]]);
  queryAddRow(report, [["Princess","Texture","Rose Pink",1712,3,"20 litres"]]);
  queryAddRow(report, [["Princess","Texture","Ivory",1704,1,"20 litres"]]);
  queryAddRow(report, [["Princess","Texture","Off White",1701,3,"20 litres"]]);
  queryAddRow(report, [["Princess","Texture","Off White",1701,3,"20 litres"]]);
</cfscript>

<!--- add groupRowspan and groupTotalQuantity columns --->
<cfscript>
  queryAddColumn(report, "groupRowspan", "integer", []);
  queryAddColumn(report, "groupTotalQuantity", "integer", []);
  if(report.RecordCount) {
      lastQueryRowToUpdate = 0;
      lastProductType = lastPaintType = lastLitreName = "";
      groupRowspan = 0;
      groupTotalQuantity = 0;
      for(rowNum=1; rowNum<=report.RecordCount; rowNum++) {
          if((report.productTypeName[rowNum] is not lastProductType) or (report.paintType[rowNum] is not lastPaintType) or (report.litreName[rowNum] is not lastLitreName)) {
              if(lastQueryRowToUpdate) {
                  querySetCell(report, "groupRowspan", groupRowspan, lastQueryRowToUpdate);
                  querySetCell(report, "groupTotalQuantity", groupTotalQuantity, lastQueryRowToUpdate);
              }
              lastQueryRowToUpdate = rowNum;
              lastProductType = report.productTypeName[rowNum];
              lastPaintType = report.paintType[rowNum];
              lastLitreName = report.litreName[rowNum];
              groupRowspan = 0;
              groupTotalQuantity = 0;
          }
          groupRowspan++;
          if(isValid("integer", report.quantity[rowNum])) {
              groupTotalQuantity += report.quantity[rowNum];
          }
          if((rowNum is report.RecordCount) and lastQueryRowToUpdate) {
              querySetCell(report, "groupRowspan", groupRowspan, lastQueryRowToUpdate);
              querySetCell(report, "groupTotalQuantity", groupTotalQuantity, lastQueryRowToUpdate);
          }
      }
  }
</cfscript>

<!--- table w/ rowspan --->
<table>
  <tr style="background-color:#cce;">
    <th>ITEM</th>
    <th>QUANTITY</th>
    <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
    <th>REMARKS</th>
  </tr>
  <cfloop query="report">
    <tr style="background-color:#ccc;">
      <cfoutput>
      <td>#report.CurrentRow#</td>
      <td>#report.quantity#</td>
      <td>#report.productTypeName# #report.paintType# #report.paintColor# #report.paintCode#</td>
      <cfif isValid("integer", report.groupRowspan)>
        <td rowspan="#report.groupRowspan#">#report.groupTotalQuantity# bags of #report.productTypeName# #report.paintType# with #report.litreName#</td>
      </cfif>
      </cfoutput>
    </tr>
  </cfloop>
</table>
```

Thanks!,

-Aaron

Comment: Aaron. Thanks..! But i am taking the result from mysql database.. How will that go? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, i got how to take datas from my database.. Thanks @aaron... Can you help me on how i can also group with litres. i.e Only the rows that have the same product type, paint type, and litre should be rowspan. Thanks!

Comment: Yvw. I've edited the code to also group with litres (you can click the "edited.." link to see a before/after comparison of the changes I just made). Also, include litrename in your getlistofbuyings query's order by: "ORDER BY pp.producttypename, pts.paintype, l.litrename" HTH!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like dead code

```
<cfset ArrayAppend(arrOfUsers ...
```

The `<cfloop>` and `<tr>` are not balanced

```
<tr class="item-row">

        <cfset curm = #getlistofbuyings.currentrow#>

                <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(arrOfUsers)#" index="i">
```

...

```
      </tr>
    </cfloop>
```

It would be useful to use http://validator.w3.org

Comment: Hello @aaron. This is exactly what i wanted! But the problem i have is that i am getting those data from the database.. (Mysql).... Please, help me modify the code. Thanks!

Comment: This is the query i am using to display the output for ITEM, QUANTITY and DESCRIPTION...

<cfquery datasource="ysr" name="getlistofbuyings">
 SELECT p.*, pt.paintcode, pt.producttypeid, pt.paintcolor, pt.painttypeid, pt.mastercode, pp.producttypename, pts.paintype, l.litrename, l.litreid
 FROM purchase p, paint pt, producttype pp, painttype pts, litre l
 WHERE p.transactionid = #transactionid#
 AND p.paintid = pt.paintid
 AND pt.producttypeid = pp.producttypeid
 AND pt.painttypeid = pts.painttypeid
 AND pt.litreid = l.litreid 
 ORDER BY pp.producttypename, pts.paintype ASC
 
</cfquery>

Comment: @aaron This is the query for REMARKS to calculate quantity... <cfquery datasource="ysr" name="numvb">
    SELECT p.*, COUNT(purchaseid) as pan, SUM(quantity) as quani, pa.*, py.*, pp.producttypename, l.litrename
    FROM purchase p, paint pa, painttype py, producttype pp, litre l
    WHERE p.transactionid = #transactionid#
    AND p.paintid = pa.paintid
    AND pa.painttypeid = py.painttypeid
    AND pa.litreid = l.litreid
    AND pa.producttypeid = #producttypeid#
    AND py.painttypeid = #painttypeid#
    AND pa.producttypeid = pp.producttypeid
    AND l.litreid = #litreid#
   
   </cfquery>

Comment: @aaronneff Please, help me with this! I will be very grateful... I want the ITEM, QUANTITY, DESCRIPTION to be outputted directly from the database, and the REMARK should rowspan all the rows that have the same Product type and paint type and show a single output of the total quantity of those rows that are rowspaned! THanks! I will be expecting from you...

Comment: Thanks @aaron.. Very Grateful!