# How can I make a column rowspan a row considering the number of item associated with it

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfml

I was Having a problem with showing a table with different columns.

The last column should rowspan each item(or row) associated with it. My code worked on ColdFusion 11 but when I tried it on ColdFusion 8 it throws an error.

The error starts from the "cfscript" (the `queryAddColumn`).  This is the code below. I modified it. The original code is here ([How Can I Output a Remark Column with rowspan Without Duplicates for same group in Coldfusion (Re formated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080562/how-can-i-output-a-remark-column-with-rowspan-without-duplicates-for-same-group/34100089))..

```
<cfquery datasource="ysr" name="report">
    SELECT p.*, p.quantity as quantity, pt.paintcode as paintCode, pt.producttypeid, pt.grouptypeid, pt.paintcolor, pt.painttypeid, pt.mastercode, pp.producttypename as productTypeName, pts.paintype as paintType, pt.*, l.litrename as litreName, l.litreid, pt.none
    FROM purchase p, paint pt, producttype pp, painttype pts, litre l
    WHERE p.transactionid = #transactionid#
    AND p.paintid = pt.paintid
    AND pt.producttypeid = pp.producttypeid
    AND pt.painttypeid = pts.painttypeid
    AND pt.litreid = l.litreid 
    ORDER BY pp.producttypename, pts.paintype ASC

</cfquery>


<!--- add groupRowspan and groupTotalQuantity columns --->
<cfscript>
  queryAddColumn(report, "groupRowspan", "integer", []);
  queryAddColumn(report, "groupTotalQuantity", "integer", []);
  if(report.RecordCount) {
      lastQueryRowToUpdate = 0;
      lastProductType = lastPaintType = lastLitrename = lastgrouptypeid = "";
      groupRowspan = 0;
      groupTotalQuantity = 0;
      for(rowNum=1; rowNum<=report.RecordCount; rowNum++) {
          if((report.productTypeName[rowNum] is not lastProductType) or (report.paintType[rowNum] is not lastPaintType)  or (report.litrename[rowNum] is not lastlitrename) or (report.grouptypeid[rowNum] is not lastgrouptypeid) ) {
              if(lastQueryRowToUpdate) {
                  querySetCell(report, "groupRowspan", groupRowspan, lastQueryRowToUpdate);
                  querySetCell(report, "groupTotalQuantity", groupTotalQuantity, lastQueryRowToUpdate);
              }
              lastQueryRowToUpdate = rowNum;
              lastProductType = report.productTypeName[rowNum];
              lastPaintType = report.paintType[rowNum];
              lastLitrename = report.litrename[rowNum];
              lastGrouptypeid = report.grouptypeid[rowNum];
              groupRowspan = 0;
              groupTotalQuantity = 0;
          }
          groupRowspan++;
          if(isValid("integer", report.quantity[rowNum])) {
              groupTotalQuantity += report.quantity[rowNum];
          }
          if((rowNum is report.RecordCount) and lastQueryRowToUpdate) {
              querySetCell(report, "groupRowspan", groupRowspan, lastQueryRowToUpdate);
              querySetCell(report, "groupTotalQuantity", groupTotalQuantity, lastQueryRowToUpdate);
          }
      }
  }
</cfscript>
```

This is th html code for outputing

```
<table id="items" bgcolor="">

         <a name="afteradding"> 
          <tr bgcolor="#ccccee">
              <th>ITEM</th>
              <th>QUANTITY</th>
              <th  class="blank" colspan="3">DESCRIPTION</th>
              <th>LITRES</th>
              <th>REMARKS</th>
          </tr>
          </a>



             <cfloop  query="report">
            <tr class="item-row">


                    <cfoutput>

            <th>#report.CurrentRow#</th>


            <th>#report.quantity#</th>

             <th colspan="3" class="description"><span><Cfif #grouptypeid# eq "">#report.productTypeName#</Cfif> <cfif #grouptypeid# neq ""><cfelse>#report.paintType# </cfif>#report.paintColor# <Cfif #grouptypeid# eq "">#report.paintCode#</Cfif> <cfif #grouptypeid# neq ""><cfelse>#report.litrename#</cfif></span></th>
             <cfif isValid("integer", report.groupRowspan)>

            <th rowspan="#report.groupRowspan#"><cfif #grouptypeid# neq ""><cfelse>#report.litrename#</cfif></th>

            <cfquery datasource="ysr" name="ysroo">
                SELECT grouptypename
                FROM grouptype
                WHERE grouptypeid = '#grouptypeid#'
            </cfquery>

        <th rowspan="#report.groupRowspan#">#report.groupTotalQuantity#<cfif #grouptypeid# eq ""> <cfif #report.litreid# eq 1>Drums<cfelse>Gallons</cfif> of #report.productTypeName# #report.paintType#</cfif>  <cfif #grouptypeid# neq ""> #ysroo.grouptypename# of #paintcolor#</cfif></th>
            </cfif>
                </cfoutput>
          </tr>
            </cfloop>

    <!---     <tr id="hiderow">
            <td colspan="5"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
              <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">$875.00</div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
              <td class="total-value"><div id="total">$875.00</div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount Paid</td>

              <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid">$0.00</textarea></td>
          </tr>
    --->

        <cfquery datasource="ysr" name="chktranbs">
            SELECT COUNT(purchaseid) purchase
            FROM purchase
            WHERE transactionid = #transactionid#
        </cfquery>



        </table>
```

Comment: Wheres the HTML? when you say "rowspan" you mean in an HTML table yes?

Comment: It sounds like you are really asking, how to make CF11 code work under CF8. The answer is to get rid of the CF9+ specific features, like array shorthand `[]`, etcetera which is not supported in CF8.  (BTW, Do you have a choice about version, because CF8 is a bit long in the tooth and was EOL'd).

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for your response! I quite understood you.. But remember i said i wasn't the one who wrote the code.. I will be grateful if you can assist in modifying it to work on CF8.. Thanks! Reply soon.

Comment: @MarkAKruger Thanks! I forgot to add that.. But i have showed  it.. Any help?

Comment: @Aaron You can also help! Sorry for disturbing.. Thanks.

Comment: I nominate @Leigh to answer the question.  I was going to until I saw her comment.

Comment: Really? @DanBracuk You could also help.. I will be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: SO is a polite site. Leigh presented the answer first and should get credit. She just happened to do so in a comment.

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes.. That is true.. I also gave her a Thank You..  I understand your intention.. But since you know where i am missing something you could help with the code.. We are here to help and develop our self.. I hope Leigh Should understand.. Thanks. Reply soon.

Comment: Replace `[]` with `arrayNew(1)`.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks to you too.. @DanBracuk Will try that now

Comment: @DanBracuk It throws another error saying :

ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
=

The CFML compiler was processing:

A script statement beginning with lastProductType on line 298, column 7.
A script statement beginning with { on line 296, column 26.
A script statement beginning with if on line 296, column 3.
A cfscript tag beginning on line 290, column 2.


please, i would love it if you can help in checking the whole cfscript code and replying with a modified that will work with CF 8.. Thanks in Advance

Comment: That's a lot of expectation for a stackoverflow post. You _are_ expected to read the CF 9 release notes and find some things on your own. :)

Comment: Thanks @DanBracuk. Always appreciated.  I was too fried to post anything coherent last night, but it looks like Mark has it covered :)

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for your concern too. Take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance two things appear incompatable with CF 9 (and your lucky - I happen to be procrastinating this mornings so noodling with this was convenient).

First there is the array constructor that super-genius-guru @Leigh has already pointed out to you. So this:

```
  queryAddColumn(report, "groupRowspan", "integer", []);
```

Needs to be replaced with this:

```
  queryAddColumn(report, "groupRowspan", "integer", ArrayNew(1));
```

The second thing that jumps is the aggregate set statement. I believe that this syntax:

```
 lastProductType = lastPaintType = lastLitrename = lastgrouptypeid = "";
```

...may have been new as of CF9. Try this:

```
 lastProductType = "";
lastPaintType = "";
lastLitrename = "";
lastgrouptypeid = "";
```

I believe the operands (<=) and incrementers (++, +=) were introduced in CF8. If they were then they are probably ok - but I could be wrong.

Comment: awesome... glad I could help. But just know we are not enabling you any more from here on in. :D

Comment: Didn't get you.. here on in?

Comment: I mean that this was a bit of extra "tutorial like" help that involved information you could have gleaned by examining the release notes of CF9. So don't always expect someone to jump in and give you that much help. That's all. Your still welcome and I _am_ glad I could help. :)

Comment: Ok.. I get you.. Thanks!